Ubuntu Desktop crashed each time over RDP
I purchased a Linux VPS from Hostinger, and it is running with Ubuntu 24.04. Now I need to use Ubuntu desktop with the help of RDP, so I followed this guide, but now when I try to access the desktop over RDP, after inputting the user and password I get this error screen and it does not shows any particular error.

Oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred and the system can't recover.

Just an FYI, but I don't think the instructions you followed were very good; they are rather outdated, are for a different release (22.04) than what you're using & contain some details written for 20.04 (focal) too (screenshots are 20.04 which is what instructions were probably written for, then updated for 22.04)

@guiverc, what should i do now sir?

I can't provide advice; firstly you didn't tell us exactly what you did; only provided a link to a set of instructions (I didn't think much of) which may or may not be what you did, in that we don't know how closely you followed instructions, or if you made any mistakes. You can view command history, or package changes in apt logs etc, which can provide refreshers of what you did, but I won't guess from your provided question details sorry.
